# Liferay redirect from http to https not working correctly

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I currently have a portal created with Liferay 7.1 and when I copy a url from http and paste it into the browser (converting it to https), it concatenates an extra /es/web in the url, so it does not find the resource and gives an error . Currently, in the configuration I have set the url to show the selected language (in this case 'es' from Spain) and also a /web. What can be happening? Is it a configuration issue of the portal itself?

I hope to find out if it is a Liferay configuration problem, that due to some parameter, it is concatenating these two words in an erroneous way or, it is a matter of the access server.

Comment: Please give more details. I have no idea where to start to reproduce. Check [mcve] and [ask]. Also, make sure that the question has a programming angle, see [help/on-topic].

Comment: Hi Olaf,
The error that occurs is because I try to copy the url from http (For example: http://www.example.es/es/web/home/fondo-documental/estadisticas) and when I expose it to the outside (in the company's social networks) when users click on that link, it redirects them to this: https://www.example.es/es/webes/web/home/fondo-documental/estadisticas. As you can see, there are twice the same parameters (es/web). The problem with this is that, when redirecting them to that page, the result is that the requested resource is not found.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming problem, but one of setup/configuration (unless there's custom code involved). Consider bringing it over to https://liferay.dev where it's on-topic

Comment: Hi Olaf, Also create a post on liferay.dev. I provide you here the link: https://liferay.dev/ask/questions/development/liferay-redirect-from-http-to-https-not-working-correctly